# which line of code decide a iOS project use storyboard or nib or neither?

Tags: ios, xcode

When I create a single view project in xcode, it will generate a storyboard. And I deleted this file, I can still run the program. So I'm just curious how can I change a storyboard project to a empty project in code?

Comment: Your target/Main Interface ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove entry "Main storyboard file base name" in your project plist file.

[image]